# bundle install gives error: OpenSSL::X509::StoreError: X509_LOOKUP_load_file: system lib

Tags: ruby, bdd

I am using a ruby selenium BDD Cucumber framework. Before executing I am doing the setup and when I do the 'Bundle install' get the below error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vszA2.png)

I have run 'gem install bundler -v 2.3.24' which is success.
It's the 1st time I am using a ruby framework
**% bundle install
--- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE -------------------------------------------------------

````
OpenSSL::X509::StoreError: X509_LOOKUP_load_file: system lib
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:292:in `add_file'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:292:in `bundler_cert_store'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:250:in `connection'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:90:in `initialize'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:288:in `new'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:288:in `block in fetchers'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:286:in `map'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:286:in `fetchers'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:432:in `block in remote_specs'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:431:in `remote_specs'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:131:in `specs'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:167:in `index_for'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:175:in `results_for'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:112:in `search_for'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:255:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:252:in `each'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:252:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:48:in `start'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:23:in `resolve'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:269:in `resolve'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:180:in `resolve_remotely!'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:280:in `resolve_if_needed'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:82:in `block in run'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in `block in lock'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `open'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `lock'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:71:in `run'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:23:in `install'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in `run'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:255:in `block in install'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/settings.rb:131:in `temporary'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:254:in `install'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in `with_friendly_errors'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
  /Users/srivas02/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
```**
````